# Optimal image storing?

Tags: sql, mysql, image, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [manage uploaded files in database or file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707629/manage-uploaded-files-in-database-or-file-system)

Hi!

I'm currently developing a website I just want to know of it is more optimal to store images in a table(MySQL) or to store the reference to an image in the table ? In the latter, the image is stored in a directory in a server instead of SQL-database

Many thanks

Comment: I wouldn't even make a reference in the database. But rather in filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Per Preet in comments, [manage uploaded files in database or file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707629/manage-uploaded-files-in-database-or-file-system) asks this same question.

I'm pretty certain most people will tell you to keep the files on the filesystem rather than stuffing them in blobs in your DB.